# Need help adding data to a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My first View Controller has a TableView.

On a second view controller, the user will input data and click a button.

I want this button to add the data to the table view, but I can not figure out how to do this.

```
var textArray: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.textArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}



@IBOutlet weak var addData: UIButton!

@IBAction func addData(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.textArray.addObject(textField.text)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

It also brings up an error for my `reloadData` line of code.

Comment: This might be helpful... The answer in in objective-c, but the principles remain the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540141/how-can-i-pass-information-from-one-view-controller-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the code you have quoted is in the second view controller. The IBAction in that view controller can't reload the self.tableview because that table is in the first view controller.

To do what you are looking to so there are literally dozens of approaches each with pluses and minuses. Maybe the easiest to implement is:

1. Creating a public variable in your second view controller called `textArray`.
2. Set the public variable in the prepareForSegue to the data source of the table in the first view controller.
3. Add the string to that variable in the IBAction of the second view controller `self.textArray.addObject(textField.text)`.
4. add the `self.tableView.reloadData()` line to the viewWillAppear function of the first view controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so new to this. How do i set a variable as a data source?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to save data in one view, and then load that data in another view, you need to save the data ether locally, or on a server. To save in locally you can use NSUserdefault.

Let the user add obejcts to an array. Then save the array on the phone to load it later, using NSUserdefault.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("yourArray", forKey: "nameYourArrayToGetItLater")
defaults.synchronize()
```

And use this code to get it back, and load it in to your TableView.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.stringForKey("nameYourArrayToGetItLater")
"yourArrayforTheTabelView" = defaults
```

If you want to store your TableView data on a server. You might want to look at this tutorial:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

Good luck!

Comment: If all you want to do is pass data from one view to another, there's no need to save anything locally or on a server, that's what passing variables is for...